# Is any braid group generated by finite "transpositions"?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, knot-theory, braid-groups

I know that any finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group of the same order. That got me thinking that finite braid groups (which I just recently learned are a thing) seem like they might be generated by a subset of all the "transpositions". Is that a concept even? Can I call the element of a braid group that just swaps the "landing" position of two strings a transposition?

Comment: What are finite braid groups(outside of the trivial group)? Fundamental groups of configuration spaces which are not the usual one(and happen to be finite)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Generators_and_relations), these elements that swap two adjacent strands do generate the braid groups and [finite braid groups](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseay/doc/braids.pdf). In the latter link, such elements are referred to as "elementary braids." Calling them "transpositions" may be confusing, because it's not clear that these correspond to transpositions in the isomorphic subgroup of $S_n$ (maybe they do, but it's not obvious to me).

Comment: There is a natural map $B_n\rightarrow S_n$ which maps the so-called "elementary braids" to transpositions. This is the map defined by considering the location of the "end" of each strand (and forgetting the braiding). It's kernel is called the "pure braid group" and is well-studied.